# Run Gitlab Pages on a relative url

Tags: gitlab

I checked the [Gitlab administrator documentation](https://FATAL:%20RuntimeError:%20Unsupported%20GitLab%20Pages%20external%20URL%20path:%20/pages), but they only state sub-urls are forbidden. I currently have gitlab running in a docker container at `https://my-domain.com/gitlab` and wanted to setup gitlab pages at `https://my-domain.com/pages`, however I get the following error when starting the container:

```
FATAL: RuntimeError: Unsupported GitLab Pages external URL path: /pages
```

In `gitlab.rb` I configured the following

```bash
pages_external_url "https://my-domain.com/pages"
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
```

Is there a workaround for this? I can't use a different url.

Gitlab version is `gitlab/gitlab-ce:15.1.6-ce.0`